# Apache Cordova to a Web API 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, cordova

I'm trying to create a Apache Cordova app that communicates to a Web api 2.0.  I can't even get it to login correctly.  I have all the required CORS loaded on the Web api.  I created a website using the same javascript functions and it works, however it will not work in the Cordova project.  I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  I've tried jsonp and nothing seems to work.  Here's my code

```
var loginData = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: 'myname',
            password: 'mypassword'
        };

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/webservices/rapidtrackapi/token',
            data: loginData
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('p').text('Success');
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        });
```

Comment: Check your config.xml for access origin settings. For development, `<access origin="*" />` usually works, but not all platforms support the wildcard (ie BB10.)  Lastly, use something like fiddler to look at the headers sent from your api and _ensure_ they have the proper headers.

Comment: I have the <access origin="*"/> set I also have included <access origin="https://www.mywebsite.com"/> and I have checked it with fiddler.  Same problem.  I've included $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; at the beginning of the call.  I've gone into the simulator and tried it set to Local, Remote, and None under network settings.  Sometimes I get an error saying grant_type unsupported.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I just couldn't let this go.  I figured it out.  Dumbest mistake ever.  Works on the localhost not working when published to IIS.  I forgot to included the database credentials in the web.config file. So it was throwing errors when trying to connect to the database to authenticate the user.